# Implementing a square partition in Java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, shapes

I'm facing a conceptual problem. I'd like to implement an Android game, in which one of the functionalities is: each time I touch a square, it is partitioned into 4 smaller squares of the same size. Every next square is partitioned the same way, up to the limit of, let's say, 1/1024 of the original size. Here's a small illustration:

[image]

And the thing is, I'm not sure how to store this data in an optimum way. I need to store the size of every piece, so that it knows to what size should it shrink after the division. If, for example, after 1st touch and 1st division, my array (for 16 element limit) would look like:

```
0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 1
2 2 3 3 
2 2 3 3
```

then if I touch the top-left square, the next array would be sth like:

```
[0,0] [0,1] 1 1 
[0,2] [0,3] 1 1
   2     2  3 3
   2     2  3 3
```

Or at least that's what I could think of. This however looks complex to implement, introduces additional dimensions in every next iteration, and I'm not really sure how to do it right. Any ideas?

Comment: You could take initial variable as 1024(as you maintained) and divide it by 2 and assign result to each separated squares after touching..

Comment: `I'm not sure how to store this data in an optimum way.` Start by defining a target function to optimise.

Comment: @vrundpurohit  This will not work, because after that I will not be able to distinguish which square lies where, as neighbouring cells will have the same array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a quadtree. Pseudo-code is given below:

```
public class QuadTree {
    private QuadTree[] children;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double size;

    public QuadTree(double x, double y, double size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void divide() {
        if (children == null) {
            children = new QuadTree[4];
            double s = 0.5 * size;
            children[0] = new QuadTree(x, y, s);
            children[1] = new QuadTree(x + s, y, s);
            children[2] = new QuadTree(x, y + s, s);
            children[3] = new QuadTree(x + s, y + s, s);
        }
    }

    public QuadTree getChild(int index) {
        if (children == null)
            return null;
        else
            return children[index];
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is regarding the optimum way of saving the squares' coordinate, i prefer defining a custom class which has 4 properties, Xtopleft, Ytopleft, Xbottomright, Ybottomright (let's call it SquarePosition) and put all the squares position objects in a collection such as Set of SquarePosition

Of course you need to override the equals method of the custom class

for example, you have square board like this:

1 2 3 3

4 5 3 3

6 6 7 7

6 6 7 7

you can have set collection like this:
{(1,1),(1,1)}, {(2,1),(2,1)}, {(3,1),(4,2)}, {(1,2),(1,2)}, {(2,2),(2,2)}, {(1,3),(2,4)}, {(3,3),(4,4)}